# Old file gets downloaded from the website

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, internet-explorer, webserver

This problem is little bit difficult to troubleshoot,but let me know anyone had the same issue. In some Computer i found that the browser downloads old file from a website instead of new file. From one of website i was trying to download a file and it gets downloaded properly. But for same url at the same time in another pc the file downloaded was different(old file) but same file name. It is not specific to a browser.It happened in about 5 PC where old file gets downloaded. What may be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you verify that the md5 hashes of the files are in fact different? Also, please give examples of what kinds of files they are, file names and where they are downloaded from, and what leads you to believe they are different.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 I am pretty sure that they are different.It is a zip file which consists of some .xsd(xml schema) files.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: If you're not gonna put more effort into answering my questions I'm out

Comment: the link of file download is https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/Portal/DownloadUtil/Schemas/2013-14.zip?5.063  Also files downloaded where different as i said before.Even md5 hash is different. If you want more information please ask